# Adding more records to Existing Excel file

Tags: php

I have one Excel file which is formatted and one record exists
I have to add more records in above existing excel file after 
existing first record without disturbing first record
using php code from mysql data and without using phpexcel of like that

Comment: What did you mean _first record_. It's first row OR already exist all records?

Comment: `without using phpexcel of like that`. Good luck. Unless your Excel file is really a CSV file, it is a HUGE amount of work to update an Excel file without use of any existing libraries.

Comment: there exists one record in that excel file - sheet